# Is it possible to change domain of an Elastic Beanstalk environment after it's been created?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, appdomain

So we're using the usual EB domains `<<domain>>.<<region>>.elasticbeanstalk.com`.

Yet we screwed with the `<<domain>>` part and we'd like to change it without deleting the environment completely and recreating it.

Still... I don't see how!

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of tinkering I found a hacky way to achieve it.

So no... there's no option to change it, but! You can create a new environment with the correct url and later on. In the environment action, swap url.
[image]

It literally just swaps them and then you can delete your newly created environment.

Comment: If you are using EB and you find swapping environment URLS hacky I want to warn you probably in the comming years using EB you are going to do this multiple times. I already did this to upgrade from Amazon Linux to Amazon Linux 2; and aswell to update major PHP version. If your application configuration (ebextensions/hooks) is solid (and you don't configure alot manually via de EB UI) you will prevent yourself for having some trouble down the line.

Read up on how to do blue/green deployments!

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html